# Formula to get specific color after applying mix-blend-mode difference

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider that it is possible to configure a color and a background-color to a website page (dynamically), and the color is applied to an element that has mix-blend-mode: difference.

Similar to the following:

```js
var $inputColor = $('input[name=color]'),
  $inputBackgroundColor = $('input[name=backgroundColor]'),
  $color = $('.color'),
  $background = $('.background'),
  $blend = $('.blend');

$inputColor.on('change', function() {
  $color.css('color', $inputColor.val());
  $blend.css('color', $inputColor.val());
}).trigger('change');

$inputBackgroundColor.on('change', function() {
  $background.css('background-color', $inputBackgroundColor.val());
}).trigger('change');
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
 }

.color,
.background {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.blend {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Color: <input type="text" name="color" value="#9933ff" /></label>
<label>Background color: <input type="text" name="backgroundColor" value="#bdc9d1" /></label>

<div class="color">I want this color</div>

<div class="background">
  <div class="blend">Element with blend mode "difference" with wanted color</div>
</div>
```

As expected, the wanted color blended with the background-color gives its difference.

So I started to think how could I achieve the wanted color with the blend mode difference applied.

I assumed that if I calculated the difference color beforehand and applied it to the blend, I would get the wanted color. Thinking that the difference of the difference would cancel itself, but this is not the case, even though it works with some colors.

The given example is one case where it doesn't work, and you can see bellow how I was trying to achieve this:

```js
var $inputColor = $('input[name=color]'),
  $inputBackgroundColor = $('input[name=backgroundColor]'),
  $color = $('.color'),
  $colorDifference = $('.color-difference'),
  $background = $('.background'),
  $blend = $('.blend'),
  $blendDifference = $('.blend-difference');

$inputColor.on('change', function() {
  var colorDifference = findDifferenceColor($inputColor.val(), $inputBackgroundColor.val());
  
  $color.css('color', $inputColor.val());
  $blend.css('color', $inputColor.val());
  $colorDifference.css('color', colorDifference);
  $blendDifference.css('color', colorDifference);
}).trigger('change');

$inputBackgroundColor.on('change', function() {
  var colorDifference = findDifferenceColor($inputColor.val(), $inputBackgroundColor.val());
  
  $background.css('background-color', $inputBackgroundColor.val());
  $colorDifference.css('color', colorDifference);
  $blendDifference.css('color', colorDifference);
}).trigger('change');

// Return Hex of difference between two colors
function findDifferenceColor(color, backgroundColor) {
  var colorRgb = hexToRgb(color),
    backgroundColorRgb = hexToRgb(backgroundColor);

  var r = Math.ceil(Math.abs((backgroundColorRgb.r / 255) - (colorRgb.r / 255)) * 255),
    g = Math.ceil(Math.abs((backgroundColorRgb.g / 255) - (colorRgb.g / 255)) * 255),
    b = Math.ceil(Math.abs((backgroundColorRgb.b / 255) - (colorRgb.b / 255)) * 255);

  return rgbToHex(r, g, b);
}

// Convert Hex to RGB
function hexToRgb(color) {
  var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(color);

  return {
    r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
    g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
    b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
  };
}

// Convert RGB to Hex
function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
  return "#" + ((1 << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b).toString(16).slice(1);
}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
 }

.color,
.background {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.blend,
.blend-difference{
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Color: <input type="text" name="color" value="#9933ff" /></label>
<label>Background color: <input type="text" name="backgroundColor" value="#bdc9d1" /></label>

<div class="color">I want this color</div>
<div class="color-difference">Difference color being applied to blend to get wanted color</div>

<div class="background">
  <div class="blend">Element with blend mode "difference" with wanted color</div>
  <div class="blend-difference">Element with blend mode "difference" with difference color</div>
</div>
```

I was clearly wrong when assumed that the difference would result in the color I wanted, and I already tried and investigated about color operations with no success, so do you have any idea how I can accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've struggled with this too. I guess you've looked at all the operations in the spec [link]https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing/#blending Unfortunately difference doesn't give the sort of exclusive OR one might need. Hope someone can come up with a good combination to make it possible.

Comment: @AHaworth I did. [link](https://codepen.io/Praseetha-KR/pen/grrWba) this is a nice reference too. I tried a lot of operations and combinations, but there is a piece of the puzzle that I'm missing and I can't really understand how to get it.